# SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true has no effect in .env settings for in a react/node project

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, eslint

I have a reactjs/node project setup (Intellij IDE) and every time I save something in a source file I get miles or warnings in the terminal.
I have set "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true" in the .env and .env.development files to no effect.

I think I disabled check in the IntelliJ settings and still keep getting this.

Any suggestions on what else to try or where to look for a fix for this?

[image]

UPDATE: To be fair, all that could be fixed, but that's not really within the scope of the project and, at this point, is just a nuisance.

Comment: so... just fix your code? Those linting errors look pretty "yeah, you don't want that in your code" to me. (never compare with `==` or `!=` in JS, unless you know _exactly_ why you _need_ type coercion, at which point you already know you don't want type coercion. And escaping when you don't have to escape just makes strings/regex harder to read)

Answer (score 1):

What you see in console are warnings coming from ESLint ([eqeqeq](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/eqeqeq), [no-useless-escape](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-useless-escape)). The `PREFLIGHT_CHECK` consists only of `verifyPackageTree`, i.e. it just checks the project dependencies; disabling this check allows to avoid the warnings about incompatible dependencies but doesn't disable the ESLint checks.
If fixing the errors is not an option for you, try disabling these rules in your ESLint configuration file.